# Update de Many-To-Many EntityFramework não funciona

Tags: entity-framework

Tenho um relacionamento N:N entre Atividade e Projeto, onde uma atividade tem muitos projetos:

```
public class Atividade : ObjetoPersistente
{

    public Atividade()
    {
        StatusAtividade = EStatusAtividade.NaoIniciado;
        TipoAtividade = ETipoAtividade.NovaImplementacao;
        Usuario = new Usuario();
        Projetos = new List<Projeto>();
    }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(FormatoDataHoraMinutoNullableConverter))]
    public DateTime? DataHoraFim { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(FormatoDataHoraMinutoNullableConverter))]
    public DateTime? DataHoraInicio { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoAtividade { get; set; }
    public string EstimativaInicialAtividade { get; set; }      

    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public string LoginUsuario
    {
        get { return Usuario.Login; }
    }      

    public EStatusAtividade StatusAtividade { get; set; }

    public string DescricaoStatusAtividade
    {
        get { return StatusAtividade.Descricao; }
    }           

    public string DescricaoTipoAtividade
    {
        get { return TipoAtividade.Descricao; }
    }

    public ETipoAtividade TipoAtividade { get; set; }
    public string TituloAtividade { get; set; }

    public long CodigoUsuario
    {
        get { return Usuario.Codigo; }
        set { Usuario.Codigo = value; }
    }

    public List<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }


    public List<long> CodigoProjetos
    {
        get { return ObtenhaListaDeCodigosPorListaDeObjetos(Projetos); }

        set { Projetos = ObtenhaListaDeObjetoPorListaDeCodigos<Projeto>(value); }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is Atividade) && (obj as Atividade).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Codigo.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Projeto:

```
public class Projeto : ObjetoPersistente, IObjetoElementoOption
{       
    public string Nome { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (obj is Projeto) && (obj as Projeto).Codigo.Equals(Codigo);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Codigo.GetHashCode();
    }

    public string Valor
    {
        get { return Codigo.ToString(); }
    }

    public string Descricao {
        get { return Nome; }
    }
}
```

Os mapeamentos estão desta forma:

```
    public AtividadeMap()
    {
        HasKey(a => a.Codigo);

        ToTable("tb_atividade");

        Property(a => a.TituloAtividade).HasColumnName("titulo_atividade");
        Property(a => a.DescricaoAtividade).HasColumnName("descricao_atividade");
        Property(a => a.DataHoraInicio).HasColumnName("data_hora_inicio");
        Property(a => a.DataHoraFim).HasColumnName("data_hora_fim");
        Property(a => a.Codigo).HasColumnName("pk_atividade");
        Property(a => a.StatusAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("status_atividade");
        Property(a => a.EstimativaInicialAtividade).HasColumnName("estimativa_inicial_atividade");
        Property(a => a.TipoAtividade.Identificador).HasColumnName("tipo_atividade");
        Property(a => a.CodigoUsuario).HasColumnName("fk_usuario");

        HasRequired(a => a.Usuario)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.CodigoUsuario);

        HasMany(a => a.Projetos)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(pa =>
            {
                pa.MapLeftKey("fk_atividade");
                pa.MapRightKey("fk_projeto");
                pa.ToTable("tb_atividade_projeto");
            });
    }


public class ProjetoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Projeto>
{
    public ProjetoMap()
    {            
        HasKey(a => a.Codigo);

        ToTable("tb_projeto");

        Property(p => p.Codigo).HasColumnName("pk_projeto");
        Property(a => a.Nome).HasColumnName("nome");
    }

}
```

O processo de consulta está OK, porém, inclusões e alterações não funcionam.

**O que está faltando?**

Após pesquisar sobre o assunto, achei várias respostas como essa, que em resumo, na minha situação, eu teria que carregar cada *Projeto* da lista do objeto *Atividade* para realizar um *Attach* na classe de contexto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631309/updating-many-to-many-navigation-property-in-entity-framework-6-changes-not-bei

**Esta é a unica forma de realizar um update na situação de relacionamentos many-to-many? Poderia tornar genérica a persistência destes relacionamentos?**

Comment: Exato, é confuso no começo. Você precisa recuperar os objetos e dar attach, se não fizer e tentar adicionar, o framework provavelmente irá criar NOVOS objetos em vez de usar os antigos.
Se você conseguir o que precisava, resuma o que precisou como resposta. Essa pergunta é bem importante.

Comment: @RSinohara na verdade eu já vi funcionando desta forma, porém, estou interessado em vias mais simplificadas e otimizadas para fazer isso.

Comment: Entendo... passei um bom tempo até me acostumar com o jeito como funciona isso. E escrevi códigos gigantescos no caminho.

Comment: Eu até ia tentar responder, mas não entendi nada da sua pergunta. Não sei nem onde está a relação N para N.

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães A relação que você descreve no código é 1:N. Eu ia sugerir uma edição na pergunta e no título, mas achei que seria uma alteração muito 'pesada'. Mas acho que você deveria alterar.

Comment: Como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez observou, meu código visualiza a relação N:N de uma forma diferente das convenções de N:N do EF. Mas é uma relação N:N, assim como exemplifiquei em uma analogia na resposta dele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que entendi o que você está tentando fazer. Seu relacionamento está errado. Se um `Projeto` tem N `Atividade`s, e uma `Atividade` pertence a N `Projeto`s, você **nunca** poderia usar algo assim:

```
public class Atividade : ObjetoPersistente
{

    public Atividade()
    {
        ...
        Projetos = new List<Projeto>();
    }

    ...
    public List<Projeto> Projetos { get; set; }    
    ...
}
```

Com isso você está dizendo que uma `Atividade` tem N `Projeto`s, mas que um `Projeto` pertence a apenas uma `Atividade`.

O correto seria:

```
[Table("tb_atividade")]
public class Atividade : ObjetoPersistente
{

    public Atividade()
    {
        ...
        // Retire isso
        // Projetos = new List<Projeto>();
    }

    ...
    // Não use Projetos diretamente. Use uma tabela associativa.
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoAtividade> ProjetoAtividades { get; set; }    
    ...
}
```

`Projeto` também recebe `ProjetoAtividades`, pois é uma associação:

```
[Table("tb_projeto")]
public class Projeto : ObjetoPersistente, IObjetoElementoOption
{       
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<ProjetoAtividade> ProjetoAtividades { get; set; }  
}
```

Agora você precisa mapear também `ProjetoAtividade`:

```
[Table("tb_atividade_projeto")]
public class ProjetoAtividade
{
    [Key]
    [Column("fk_atividade")]
    public int AtividadeId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("fk_projeto")]
    public int ProjetoId { get; set; }

    // Estas são propriedades de navegação.
    // O Entity Framework carrega essas classes automaticamente.
    public virtual Projeto Projeto { get; set; }
    public virtual Atividade Atividade { get; set; }
}
```

Repare que não preciso usar *Fluent API* aqui. Posso apenas decorar as propriedades com *Attributes* e o Entity Framework faz todo o resto sozinho.

## Inclusões e Modificações

Como o mapeamento dos *Models* está errado, você precisará mapear `Codigo` nas classes para funcionar:

```
[Table("tb_atividade")]
public class Atividade : ObjetoPersistente
{
    [Key]
    // Não sei se a coluna no banco chama "codigo", mas suponho que sim.
    [Column("codigo")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    ...
}

[Table("tb_projeto")]
public class Projeto : ObjetoPersistente, IObjetoElementoOption
{       
    ...
    [Key]
    // Não sei se a coluna no banco chama "codigo", mas suponho que sim.
    [Column("codigo")]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
}
```

Sobre inclusões, para inserir uma nova associação, faça da seguinte forma:

```
// Carregue o projeto
var projeto = contexto.Projetos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Codigo == /* Coloque o valor da chave aqui */);
// Carregue a atividade
var atividade = contexto.Atividades.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Codigo == /* Coloque o valor da chave aqui */);
if (projeto != null && atividade != null)
{
    var projetoAtividade = new ProjetoAtividade 
    {
        // É assim mesmo que usa. __NUNCA__ defina o Id diretamente.
        Atividade = atividade,
        Projeto = projeto
    }

    contexto.ProjetoAtividades.Add(projetoAtividade);
    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Como a alteração para a entidade associativa não faz sentido, vou ensinar como fazer uma exclusão:

```
var projetoAtividade = contexto.ProjetoAtividades.FirstOrDefault(/* Coloque aqui a condição para selecionar a associação, aqui usando os Ids */);
if (projetoAtividade != null)
{
    contexto.ProjetoAtividades.Remove(projetoAtividade);
    contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Cigano, porém, os objetos  não estão errados. Em uma analogia, `Atividade` seria um `Carro`, e `Projeto` seria um `Acessorio`. _Um carro possui diversos acessórios, e um mesmo acessório pode pertencer a vários carros_ .

Comment: Então não é associação N para N. Sua pergunta não está bem colocada. É 1 para N. Corrija o enunciado para que eu possa corrigir a resposta, por favor.

Comment: Desculpe, melhorando a analogia: um carro pode ter banco de couro e faróis de neon. Qualquer carro pode ter estes acessórios (banco de couro e faróis de neon). Acredito que você não entendeu a analogia.

Comment: Então de fato seu código está incorreto mesmo. O Entity Framework não é o Hibernate: você não pode expressar os objetos da mesma forma.

Comment: Exatamente, Cigano. Estou atualmente utilizando NHibernate e vejo que as convenções do EntityFramework são bastante particulares. Esta foi a conclusão que tive.

Comment: Irei gratificar a melhor solução para o os dois objetos exemplificados. (Carro e Acessório) ou os do problema (Atividade e Projeto).

Comment: @JoaquimMagalhães Particularmente, nunca gostei do tipo de mapeamento do Hibernate porque ele está propenso a ambiguidades. Além disso, no caso associativo, para o caso do Hibernate, é complexo definir informações extras que pertençam à associação. Por exemplo, no seu caso (Projetos e Atividades), se eu quisesse estipular que para cada projeto a atividade tem um campo "Horas", no EF é bastante simples. O que falta para que as respostas te atendam?

Comment: A sua resposta esclareceu, realmente não era o que eu esperava. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, a priori você não precisa carregar as entidades relacionadas sempre. Especialmente quando for fazer alterações.

Agora, sempre que for usar uma referência a uma entidade que existe no banco de dados, você precisa dar `attach` ou recuperar as entities. Nem sempre buscar no banco de dados, mas precisa dar `attach` no `dbcontext`.

Curiosamente, eu tenho uma pergunta exatamente assim no SO, que não obteve resposta (e eu tive que voltar e responder): [Pergunta SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470007/entity-framework-attach-object-with-same-key-exists).

No começo parece estranho: ter que recuperar as entidades que já estão lá. Mas funciona assim. Digamos que você já tem os projetos, digamos retornados da interface de usuários em um aplicativo web. Digamos também que você confia que essses objetos estão ok. Você poderia criar uma nova atividade e inserir esses projetos, certo? Não. Se fizer isso assim, o `DBContext` vai, na verdade, criar novos projetos, pois esses que você está usando não está `attached`.

Uma forma alternativa de fazer é dar `attach` e mudar o state das entidades pra `unchanged`. Assim o `DBContext` não altera esses projetos, mas também não os modifica.

Mas no fundo, a prática de buscá-los novamente no banco é correta. Não imagino um cenário onde você possa ter objetos dettached que sejam seguros, nem que seja pelo fato que foram recuperados anteriormente (possivelmente BEM antes) possam ter sido removidos do BD.

---

Portanto, **sim**, essa lógica com attach é o único jeito de atualizar entidades com relações N:N ou 1:N.

Você pode **encapsular** isso em seus repositórios, mas não de forma **genérica**. É exatamente o fato que cada entidade tem relações especiais que faz com que sejam necessárias essas lógicas.

Comment: Enchergo o problema maior em uma situação macro, onde tenho vários relacionamentos one-to-many como este. E a ligação da chave da entidade deveria justamente encapsular essa burocracia. Por isso aguardo uma resposta mais otimista sobre isso.

Comment: Se houver, eu também vou ficar feliz :)

Comment: Eu preciso dessa resposta pq estou fazendo provas de conceito com o framework, uma migração de um projeto ADO.NET puro para um ORM, seja EF ou NHibernate... E essas situações assim como outras que já encapsulei, precisam ser genéricas, buscando produtividade.

Comment: Até onde sei é preciso fazer o attach, ou buscar no BD as entidades da relação e substituir as entities `dettached` pelas que foram buscadas. Marginalemte, você poderia carregar objetos 'vazios', mas com o ID correto, dar `attach` e setar o `status` para `unchanged`... O `DBContext` não vai inseri-los ou atualizar, e vão poder ser usados na relação N:N (ou 1:N)

Comment: Entendo. Isso em Hibernate é tão simples! Tendo as chaves mapeadas e os relacionamentos mapeados, o EF deveria subentender esse processo...

Comment: Então, mas tem a sua estranhesa, apesar de mais prático. Se o ORM vê a ID de uma entidade e já 'saca' que é um item que existe no BD, tudo bem, é prático, mas de onde venho essa ID? Se for web, por exemplo, provavelmente passou por um post. E se o usuário alterar isso? Qualquer verificação envolve verificar no BD, então porque não usar a entidade retornada? Assim, o ORM fazer isso implicitamente pode ser perigoso.